# PHP capitalize first letter of word

Tags: php

Hi I am working on simple php code ,where I have to do this :

It needs to take something like:

```
  $string =  'fiverr.com'
   $string =  'myfiverr.com'
   $string =  'myfiverrgig.com'
```

and change to:

```
Fiverr.com

MyFiverr.com

MyFiverrGig.com
```

so that it should capitalize first letter of real word. Should I use dictionary of all words or is there any php library which I can use ?

Comment: What dictionary has "fiverr" as a valid word? Also, what happens if there's multiple possible interpretations?

Comment: This is very difficult to do, even with a dictionary

Comment: You want it to convert `fivmyfiverrgigerr.com` into `MyFiverrGig.com` ?

Comment: Maybe We have to manually add new words in a dictionary (.csv file )

Comment: You're probably going to have to do this manually by making a dictionary of your own and compare it.

Comment: usually it will be domains that I have to convert them

Comment: @user9991765 so you mean `myfivvergig.com` instead of  `fivmyfiverrgigerr.com`?

Comment: like `googletranslate.com` to `GoogleTranslate.com`

Comment: This is utterly subjective. Why are your trying to capitalise domain names?

Comment: This is just a small part in my app , where user will copy paste domains into textbox and after submitting form ,it will capitalize first letter of each word like above so that they can copy and paste it on another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an array of words you want to replace, and then replace it, like this:

```
$string = 'myfivvergig.com';

$words =['my','fivver','gig'];

foreach($words as $word){
       $replace = ucfirst($word);
       $string = str_replace($word, $replace, $string);
}

return $string // MyFivverGig.com
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a php function called `ucfirst ( string $str ) : string` that does the same.
You can find the reference [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, that only works for actual words separated by spaces. It won't help for non-spaced words such as those in domains